# E-Ink/Digital Paper for Display

Tags: android, hardware

I like to play with my favourite android chess app on a tablet.

On the other hand I like the sun in my room.

I the sun is too strong, then up to now I go to a dark area in my room.

Is there a way to solve this?

Is there a way to show the chess board on E-Ink (digital paper)?

Comment: Also take a look [here](http://superuser.com/questions/1007345/turn-kindle-paperwhite-into-secondary-display) which is a question about how to use kindle reader as secondary display

Comment: Here's a webapp that works on Kindle: https://kidschess.github.io/chessjs/

Answer (score 5):

As of 2016 There are a few Android based e-ink readers, most notably by Onyx and a whole bunch of rebrands ranging in size from 6 inches to 9.7 inches.

I highly recommend checking out mobileread.com for all e-ink reader related information.

Usually they do not run the latest Android (i think 4.4.2 is about as good as it gets).

Another minus is that they do not run the most powerful CPUs(to both save on costs and also to preserve power). Still for running Stockfish they should be good enough.

Answer (score 2):

There is actually a chess app for the Kindle - [http://www.amazon.com/Chess/dp/B004KACWZW](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B004KACWZW) . I don't think it is very strong. It will probably give you a good game if your are 1800 or lower. Probably a waste of time if you are much over 2000.

Comment: Unfortunately new kindle readers doesn't support apps any more.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use online websites on your E-readers like [lichess](http://en.lichess.org/analysis).

you can play against engine, other players, analysis board, edit board, import pgn, etc.

Comment: Have you tried it? I guess modern web pages (with AJAX) don't work well on E-readers.

Comment: I think it depends on E-reader OS. There are some running Android or Linux and they can open webpages with Ajax. I tried lichess on my kindle and it doesnt work. Some other like www.puzzle-nonograms.com works fine in kindle.

Comment: Do you have list of e-readers with Android on it?

Answer (score 1):

[pbchess](http://pbchess.vlasovsoft.net/en/index.html) is available for Android and e-ink readers (Kobo, PocketBook, Kindle). I installed it on my Kobo after Kobo decided to remove the chess app (why?) and now even have the opportunity to review my opening pgn files, solve tactics and play games (much more than the preinstalled app was capable of).